# Log stdout & stderr when program is started in screen

Tags: logging, screen, stdout, stderr

I successfully added logging for the stdout/stderr of a program output to a file.

But when I start the program from `screen` the logfile is empty, because it only logs messages from `screen` and not from the program running in the background within `screen`.

Any way to fix this or other solutions please, so I can run a detachable program with stdout/stderr logging, similar to `screen`?

current startup line:

screen -A -m -d -S test ./testserver -config=config.cfg -filepatching -autoinit 1>>"./log_$(date +%s).txt" 2>>"./log_$(date +%s).txt"

Comment: Maybe you could add some information or code how you do it right now. Otherwise it's nearly impossible to guess what's wrong.

Comment: added startup line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you need to encapsulate your command. Right now `1>>"./log_$(date +%s).txt" 2>>"./log_$(date +%s).txt"` applies to screen itself, nit the program executed.

Try this instead:

```
screen -A -m -d -S test './testserver -config=config.cfg -filepatching -autoinit 1>>"./log_$(date +%s).txt" 2>>"./log_$(date +%s).txt"'
```

Or this:

```
screen -A -m -d -S test /bin/sh -c './testserver -config=config.cfg -filepatching -autoinit 1>>"./log_$(date +%s).txt" 2>>"./log_$(date +%s).txt"'
```